# send build ARtefacts over FTP not taking the source files

Tags: jenkins, ftp, jenkins-plugins

I am using the "Send build artifacts over FTP" plugin in Jenkins to send the published files of a dotNet projet on an FTP SERVER.

The problem is that if i put the real directory (as shown below), the jenkins result is :

```
FTP: Connecting from host [server03]
FTP: Connecting with configuration [FTPServer] ...
FTP: Disconnecting configuration [FTPServer] ...
FTP: Transferred 0 file(s)
```

it only works when i put * in the **source files** but it transfers wrong files (from the workspace)?

What am i missing ?

[image: my config]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'v got my own answer on this : this plugin only works with files under the workspace, it cannot take a root path